# question about proof of L’Hôpital’s Rule

Tags: calculus, limits

one version of L’Hôpital’s Rule states like this 
[image]

the following is the proof , MVT in it is the abbreviation of Mean Value Theorem.

[image]

1). we defined $f(a)= g(a) = 0$ in the proof, however , if we've already known $f(a)= g(a) ≠ 0$ for both function before , does this mean we cannot prove the Rule in this case?

2). does  $f(a)= g(a) = 0$ is a necessary condition for this version of L’Hˆopital’s Rule?

Comment: I have noticed for the first time the name "Souped up MVT" used for Cauchy's Mean Value Theorem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think that there is a small amount of inconsistency between the theorem statement and its proof you have mentioned.

The statement of the theorem clearly states that $f$ is continuous on $[a, b]$ Then I don't understand why the proof has to arbitrarily define $f(a) = 0$ and write "... hence $f$ is continuous on $[a, b)$".

Note that according to the statement of the theorem mentioned in your post, **it automatically follows that $f(a) = g(a) = 0$**. It is not a choice, but a conclusion. You may ask **How?**

Clearly $f$ is continuous on $[a, b]$ and $\lim_{x \to a^{+}}f(x) = 0$. But we know that continuity of $f$ at end-point $a$ means that $\lim_{x \to a^{+}}f(x) = f(a)$. It thus follows that $f(a) = 0$. Same way $g(a) = 0$.

Note that the proof of the theorem given in your post corresponds to this statement:

**Theorem 2 (Macho L'Hopital's Rule)**: *Suppose $f$ and $g$ are continuous on an* **open interval $(a, b)$**, *and are differentiable on the open interval $(a, b)$. Suppose that $g'(x)$ is never $0$ on $(a, b)$, and that $\lim_{x \to a^{+}}f'(x)/g'(x)$ exists, and that $\lim_{x \to a^{+}}f(x) = \lim_{x \to a^{+}}g(x) = 0$. Then* $$\lim_{x \to a^{+}}\frac{f(x)}{g(x)} = \lim_{x \to a^{+}}\frac{f'(x)}{g'(x)}$$

So you now see the difference between your statement of the theorem and this one. I think there is typo in the statement of the theorem in your book. The corrected version mentioned in previous paragraph does not say anything about the values of $f, g$ at the end-point $a$, it only talks about their limits as $x \to a^{+}$ and that is what matters for the applicability of L'Hopital's Rule.

---

**Update**: As OP has pointed out in comments, it is superfluous to mention that $f, g$ are continuous on $(a, b)$. I had mentioned it explicitly to show the typo error in the original statement of the theorem. So let's have the following version which is correct and has no redundancies:

**Theorem 2 (Macho L'Hopital's Rule)**: *Suppose $f$ and $g$ are differentiable on the open interval $(a, b)$. Suppose that $\lim_{x \to a^{+}}f'(x)/g'(x)$ exists, and that $\lim_{x \to a^{+}}f(x) = \lim_{x \to a^{+}}g(x) = 0$. Then* $$\lim_{x \to a^{+}}\frac{f(x)}{g(x)} = \lim_{x \to a^{+}}\frac{f'(x)}{g'(x)}$$

Note that we don't have any information about the behavior of $f, g$ at $x = a$. We only know that their limits exist as $x \to a^{+}$. In such cases we say that $f, g$ have a **removable discontinuity** at $x = a$ and this discontinuity can be removed by defining these functions at $x = a$ in a "suitable manner". The "suitable manner" is to define $f(a)$ to be equal to $\lim_{x \to a^{+}}f(x)$ and same for $g(a)$. This makes the functions continuous at $x = a$.

Why do we need to define $f, g$ at $x = a$? Because we want to use MVT and it requires continuity at the end points. Note further that this definition of $f, g$ at $a$ is not arbitrary, but rather is based on the fact that their limits exist (so that the discontinuity can be removed). Unless we do this we can't proceed to use MVT and complete the proof.

Note that I have also removed the condition that $g'(x)$ is never $0$. This is redundant. The condition that $f'(x)/g'(x)$ tends to a limit as $x \to a^{+}$ ensures that this ratio $f'(x)/g'(x)$ is defined in certain interval of type $(a, d)$ where $d \leq b$. And this means that denominator $g'(x)$ is non-zero in $(a, d)$.

There is another point which needs to be mentioned in the proof of L'Hospital (or perhaps in the statement of Cauchy MVT). Under the conditions of the theorem 2 above it is guaranteed that $g(x) \neq 0$ for $x \in (a, d)$ (you need to give the reason for this yourself as it is easy). And that's why we can talk of ratio $f(x)/g(x)$ and its limit.

Comment: Thanks! (1). I think there is no need to say f and g are continuous on an open interval (a,b) in your statement, because f and g are differentiable on the open interval (a,b) already mean they are continuous on the interval. (2). I saw some version of  L'Hopital's Rule that is similar to what stated here(does not say anything about the values of f,g at the end-point a), but in the proof of this sort of statement, it is usually need to define f(a)=g(a)=0, so my question in the original post also arise in this case, can you help answer them?

Comment: @iMath: I will update my answer to reply to your further queries. wait for few minutes.

Comment: Thanks very much ! Your answer is great ! So if f and g at x=a is not defined before , then we can define  f(a)=g(a)=0, if g(a)≠0 and f(a)≠0 before , then we can redefine f(a)=g(a)=0, thus removed the discontinuity so that we can use MVT to complete the proof. All in all, whether f or g is defined or not at x=a before is not that important for the limit of a function doesn't concern about if the function is defined or not at the limit point . Right ?

Comment: @iMath: yes you are right.

Answer (score 2):

$f$ and $g$ are only defined on $(a,b)$. The author is extending the definition to $[a,b)$. $f(a)$ and $g(a)$ aren't defined a priori, and he's only defining it that way for convenience sake of the proof.

Comment: I saw some version of  L'Hopital's Rule that f and g are only defined on (a,b), but then in the proof of this sort of statement, it is usually need to define f(a)=g(a)=0, so my question in the original post also arise in this case, can you help answer them?